# Linux Basic Networking and iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

If I am networking between two linux PCS, using blue ethernet cables, or wireless, is this always a tcp/ip, tcp network?

If I am networking between one Linux machine and another, will both machines require INPUT and OUTPUT rules for a network discovery protocol, and then a network use protocol, to browse and edit files and directories, or mount the filesystem, or is allow tcp/ip going to be enough for all that? What are the default networking protocols modern, stable, latest versions of Linux use? For example, through 64 bit Mint, OpenMandriva, Fedora, SystemRescueCd?

Comment: there are lots of other kinds of networks (especially historically) so theoretically you are not limited to just TCP/IP. Practically however, TCP/IP is so dominant in the modern era, that any modern PC\Server OS will default to IP, and most applications won't work properly with different network and transport layer protocols.  Mainframes are more likely to use a different networking protocol, due to the need to maintain compatibility with much older systems (you replace PCs/Servers every few years; you replace mainframes every few decades...).

Comment: Your question is _much_ too vague (so I voted to close the question). You're asking 3 semesters worth of Computer Science classes in a single question here. Simplified, all protocols you'll use will be built on TCP/IP yes. Judging by your question, you're mixing OSI layers. Something like Samba, which does "network file browsing", will be built on top of TCP/IP. TCP/IP itself covers 2 OSI layers, TCP on L4 and IP on L3. And yes, you will need appropriate firewall rules (or being a beginner, just disable the firewall first, get it to work and then start introducing the firewall).

Answer (score 0):

There are a possible 256 protocols.
TCP/IP and UDP are the protocols that are most used.

However, it should be noted that both TCP and UDP both have 0-65535 ports.
Many have different services that by default use one or more of said ports.

Both DHCP and DNS use UDP.

---

https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml

Too many exist to copy and past the whole list but here a sample.

```
Decimal,Keyword,Protocol,IPv6 Extension Header,Reference
0,HOPOPT,IPv6 Hop-by-Hop Option,Y,[RFC8200]
1,ICMP,Internet Control Message,,[RFC792]
2,IGMP,Internet Group Management,,[RFC1112]
3,GGP,Gateway-to-Gateway,,[RFC823]
4,IPv4,IPv4 encapsulation,,[RFC2003]
5,ST,Stream,,[RFC1190][RFC1819]
6,TCP,Transmission Control,,[RFC793]
7,CBT,CBT,,[Tony_Ballardie]
8,EGP,Exterior Gateway Protocol,,[RFC888][David_Mills]
9,IGP,"any private interior gateway             
(used by Cisco for their IGRP)",,[Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority]
10,BBN-RCC-MON,BBN RCC Monitoring,,[Steve_Chipman]
11,NVP-II,Network Voice Protocol,,[RFC741][Steve_Casner]
12,PUP,PUP,,"[Boggs, D., J. Shoch, E. Taft, and R. Metcalfe, ""PUP: An
Internetwork Architecture"", XEROX Palo Alto Research Center,
CSL-79-10, July 1979; also in IEEE Transactions on
Communication, Volume COM-28, Number 4, April 1980.][[XEROX]]"
13,ARGUS (deprecated),ARGUS,,[Robert_W_Scheifler]
14,EMCON,EMCON,,[<mystery contact>]
15,XNET,Cross Net Debugger,,"[Haverty, J., ""XNET Formats for Internet Protocol Version 4"",
IEN 158, October 1980.][Jack_Haverty]"
16,CHAOS,Chaos,,[J_Noel_Chiappa]
17,UDP,User Datagram,,[RFC768][Jon_Postel]
18,MUX,Multiplexing,,"[Cohen, D. and J. Postel, ""Multiplexing Protocol"", IEN 90,
USC/Information Sciences Institute, May 1979.][Jon_Postel]"
```

Comment: Could you explain why there are 256 possible protocols?

Comment: @mashuptwice  I have updated my answer.  The simplest answer is because its and 8 bit field which can handle 0-255.  The long answer is because companies went before IANA committees and got their protocols approved.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Its good to see Jon Postel's name on these. one of the most influential computer scientists of the last century, despite not writing a great deal of code. SMTP and DNS are very important, but his work curating the RFCs for decades is what really shines.

Answer (score 0):

> If I am networking between two linux PCS, using blue ethernet cables, or wireless, is this always a tcp/ip, tcp network?

Almost always - if you are assigning or see IP addresses, you're working with a TCP/IP network.  There are other transport and network protocols but none in wide use on a typical home/SOHO environment.

> If I am networking between one Linux machine and another, will both machines require INPUT and OUTPUT rules for a network discovery protocol, and then a network use protocol, to browse and edit files and directories, or mount the filesystem, or is allow tcp/ip going to be enough for all that?

It depends on the strategy you select.

- Default allow: make rules that deny if criteria is matched, if no rules apply, allow.
- Default deny: make rules that allow if criteria is matched, if no rules apply, deny.

The criteria can be anything with iptables - protocol, IP address, port, and more.

Whether you are working wth default allow or default deny depends on the "policy" of a specific iptables chain - the policy is what to do if no other rules apply.  You then add rules - which can allow, block, or go to another chain to check those rules.

Any Linux distro is going to have IPv4 and TCP enabled out of the box, you would have to do a lot of work to actually disable TCP if it's even possible.  Some distros may not have IPv6 enabled.

Don't forget you also have to take UDP into account which is used, e.g. by DNS.